# Android memory and disk cache http client using Picasso

Tags: android, caching, httpclient, disk, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images in a container. I want to cache in memory and cache in disk. 
What is the best way to cache a image in disk? What http client is the best option?

These are my requirements:

- First check cache in memory
- Check cache in disk
- Get the image from the server.

If the image is on disk -> check cache interval(max-age) and validate with server if the image is stale. The server needs in the header `if_none_match: eTag`.

I've read that this feature is built in the OkHttp api, but I don't know how to use it. Please I would appreciate somebody to send me some link, documentation or if any other different way of doing this that you could consider.

Comment: have you solved the issue, yet? I kind meet this problem with my project oo